# SNMP: How many OIDs can be requested in one PDU?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

A simple question that I can not find answer to.

I know that a GET request can be sent with multiple OIDs in PDU. How many OIDs maximum can be requested in one PDU in one request? Is there a limit in SNMP? in UDP?

Comment: A limit on UDP packet size.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer myself in this thread:
http://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/26203876/

There is not definite limit to number of varbinds in one SNMP GET request in SNMP specs. However there is a software limit to 128 OIDs in snmpget util (net-snmp).

Answer (score 1):

SNMP is an application layer protocol and UDP/TCP are transports. With UDP (IPv4) one is limited by the [16 bit length](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt) field which yields 64 KB of UDP datagram. Given the above an SNMP packet will have to be a little less than that. Depending on how many OIDs one can pack into a PDU which is a function of the length of the OIDs (and the ASN.1 transfer encoding) the total number of OIDs requested can vary. The limit of 128 is on the [sub-id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4181#section-4.6.1.5) which represents the length of a single Octet and bear in mind that this is TLV(Type Length Value) Encoding, so add a few bytes for those in the RequestPDU. In the response PDU while Type and Length of the OIDs will be the same as in RequestPDU but the value will occupy require more bytes, thereby increasing the overall size of the PDU. This extra bit regarding what "type" of OID values are being requested (specially how long these can be), also plays a role in number of OIDs that can be packed in a single ResponsePDU.

Additionally [SNMP TCP (RFC3430)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3430) and [TLS/TCP for SNMP (RFC5953)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5953.txt) are also prevalent where SNMP runs over TCP transport. There the PDUs can be longer but I feel that the cost of processing longer PDU can take its toll on SNMP agents that are running on low horse-powered devices (at least in the past). Breaking it down at PDU level will still require the SNMP application protocol level per PDU tax of authentication/data-integrity and optional privacy checks.

Interestingly in the past the very first RFC on SNMP did suggest a limit of 484 octets but also goes on to state that larger PDU handling must be supported. Here is a snippet [RFC 1157 SNMPv1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157.txt)

> *An implementation of this protocol need not accept messages
> whose length exceeds 484 octets.  However, it is recommended that
> implementations support larger datagrams whenever feasible.*

And the last bit is on the 1500 bytes referring to an ethernet frame size, that is Layer 2 (Data Link Layer) limit. The IP layer sitting on top will fragment the packet based on the MTU size however full IP packet assembly will be performed before its handed off to the upper layer [IP fragmentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791). The IP packet is then passed to transport UDP or TCP as the case may be. Eventually when the application layer receives the packet it will be a fully formed SNMP PDU (no fragmentation at that level).

Answer (score 1):

As Aniruddh correctly noted, the theoretical limit is 64kB. But the practical limit is lower. Each SNMP agent implementation has different limits, and good NMS applications will determine this limit in its discovery phase of the agent (in addition to retransmission policy, etc).

References:

1. [eHealth](https://www.ca.com/us/services-support/ca-support/ca-support-online/knowledge-base-articles.tec517935.html)
2. [Juniper](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/task/configuration/snmp-server-maximum-packet-size.html)

or google "snmp max pdu size".

Answer (score 0):

SNMP allows PDUs sized up to the MTU of the network. The buffer should be as big as the largest anticipated packet, so it should probably correspond to the MTU, if possible. For example, Ethernet allows up to 1500 byte frame payloads.

So your PDU max size is usually up to 10 varbinds in average.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply.

Comment: However SNMP packets will be broken down to multiple UDP frames and reassembled at destination. So there is still a question if there is any limit specified in SNMP protocol itself

Comment: You're not quite right here. Sure they will be reassembled at destination but you'll end up having missing chunks and reordering problems. So it is not recommended to have PDUs greater than MTU size.